# How can I set focus on the first TouchableHighlight component (or another one, given by ref for instance) inside the modal when modal is opened?

Tags: javascript, android, modal-dialog, react-native

How can I set focus to the first (or any given) TouchableHighlight component inside the modal when it's opened?
I'm using D-pad/kayboard/TV Remote

Let's use the fragment of the react-native documentation modal example:

```
<View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
  <Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={false}
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    onRequestClose={() => {
      Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
    }}>
    <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
       <View>
          <TouchableHighlight>
            <Text>Button 1</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight>
            <Text>Button 2</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight
             onPress={() => {     
           this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
             }}>
             <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
           </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
     </View>
  </Modal>
  <TouchableHighlight
     onPress={() => {
       this.setModalVisible(true);
     }}>
     <Text>Show Modal</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

Navigation with D-pad works, but when the modal is opened, the first TouchableHighlight (button 1) is not focused, focus remains on the "Show Modal" button
Or, How can I set focus on the "Button 2" TouchableHighlight programatically?

TextInput for example has autoFocus, but TouchableHighlight no, if we are using only Touchable components inside a modal, I don;t know how to autoFocus them, or set implicitely it

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean by focusing a touchable component?

Comment: I mean highlight the component, for example if you start an android emulator and start to navigate with the PC keyboard you will see how the touchables are highlight (underlayColor). React-native doc: "Access to touchable controls: When running on Android TV the Android framework will automatically apply a directional navigation scheme based on relative position of focusable elements in your views. ". This scheme works, but when the modal is opened it is not set the focus on its touchable cmponents

Answer (score 5):

Add `hasTVPreferredFocus: true` to the TouchableHighlight you want focused.

It is implemented on Android even though the documentation states that hasTVPreferredFocus is iOS-only.

Programmatically you can also force the focus by calling:

```
yourElementRef.setNativeProps({ hasTVPreferredFocus: true })
```

Comment: Thank you, I've got it, I just thought a few months ago, that this is ffor Ios only, but I was wrong

Comment: @mtkopone . is there any way to focus View component, i have a list which is inside View and i want to do some function calls when user focus on that View (onFocus,onBlur)

Comment: Only Touchable items can have focus. So if the items in your list are some sort of Touchable components, you can add onFocus/onBlur listeners to them. See: https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-apple-tv (select android)

Answer (score -1):

@mtkopone . is there any way to focus `View` component, i have a list which is inside View and i want to do some function calls when user focus on that View (onFocus,onBlur)

Comment: this can be a question itself! please take a look!

Answer (score -1):

`ref.current.setNativeProps({hasTVPreferredFocus: true});`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.